# Logit vs. Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, logistic

There is seemingly a difference whether one approaches the "logit" from statistics / econometrics:

$$F^{-1}(\pi) = \log\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right) = \text{logit}(\pi)$$ (I)

Or from the machine learning perspective, where it is typically called "logistic regression":

$$F(\eta) = \frac{\exp(\eta)}{1 + \exp(\eta)} = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\eta)}$$ (II)

There is essentially no difference between what is done to classify new observations. But what exactly does that mean the inverse of the CDF? Is there a possibility to reformulate (I) to get to (II)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set $\pi = F(\eta)=(1+\exp(-\eta))^{-1}$ and solve for $\eta$, you obtain $\eta=\log(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi})=F^{-1}(\pi)$.

In the terminology of generalised linear models (logistic regression is an example of a GLM), $F$ is the mean function and $F^{-1}$ is the link function.

Comment: Hi Dr. Milt, Thanks a lot for clarification! That solved some other problems I had as well. Now, what I still do not really get is: Why would we denote the logistic function as $F()$ and the logit as $F^{-1}()$. Is that simply intended to describe this process in your answer, where you set them equal and solve for the other parameter? Or should it tell me, that $F$ transforms the answer into a probability, whereas $F^{-1}$ gives me the log odds. I think I could not really follow your discussion with AdamO below. Maybe you could rephrase that in simpler terms. Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. In a generalised linear model (GLM), the mean of the response (in our case, the probability $\pi$) and the linear predictor ($\eta$, which is a function of covariates $X_1, X_2, \ldots$) are not on the same scale. The mean function transforms the linear predictor into the mean of the response, where the link function does the inverse.

Comment: Also, the choice of the logistic function as our mean function ($F$) is not unique. Any strictly monotonic function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$ could work. Another common choice is $\Phi(.)$, the CDF of a standard normal random variable. This is known as probit regression.

Comment: You helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Where is your notation from? $F$ is a poor choice to represent a [link function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) which is different from a CDF. The "logit" link, $g(x) = \log(x/(1-x))$, is the link function, together with a binomial variance structure, that defines logistic regression as a special case of a generalized linear model. The inverse of the logit $g^{-1}(x) = \exp(x)/(1-\exp(x))$ is the mapping that transforms the linear predictor, i.e. log-odds of response, into a response probability.

The CDF for a binary response is not a continuous function, but rather a step function with the height of the first step corresponding to the probability of a 0 response at $x=0$ and a height of 1 at $x=1$.

Comment: I would argue that $F$ is a good choice to represent the mean (not link) function specifically for logistic regression, because of its connection to the latent-variable representation. Also, it makes it clear that we could choose the link function to be the inverse of the CDF of any continuous real-valued random variable with unbounded support.

Comment: @DoctorMilt I am following McCullogh Nelder notation (except I haven't used $\eta$ and $\nu$ as inputs to the link and inverse link functions, respectively, but hopefully the points come across as expressing these as functionals).

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the standard notation is in any way worse! I just feel it's a lot more natural to think of the inverse link function in a logistic regression as the CDF of a latent variable.